# Collection sort - Positive,0,negative order

Tags: java, collections, integer

I have a Collection of Employees. Each employee has a ID. This ID number is of the format
 -x >= 0 >= x . I have to sort the Employees to be in the order 0...x  -1....-x. How can i do this??

```
List<Employee> empSort = new ArrayList(em.getEmployees());
Collections.sort(empSort, new Comparator<Employee>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Employee p1, Employee p2) {
                   // WHAT LOGIC SHOULD I DO THERE TO HAVE THEM
                                      SORTED AS 0...x -1....-x
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you want all the negative numbers to appear after the non-negative numbers in order from least negative to most negative? e.g. you want 0 < 10 < -1 < -10, even though 10 > -1 and -1 > -10

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes i want it as 0,1,2...10,-1,-2,-3...-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gave it some thought over dinner, and I like this better.

```
int sign1 = (p1 >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
int sign2 = (p2 >= 0) ? 1 : -1;

int result = Integer.compare(sign2, sign1);

if( result == 0){
    // same sign
    result = sign1 * Integer.compare(p1, p2);
}
return result;
```

output still is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, -1, -2]
```

Comment: lets say i want employees of type permanent to always be the first displayed, no matter what ID they have. How can i do this??? other types of emplyees will follow this sorting order

Comment: How about: `int permanent1 = p1.isPermanent() ? -1 : 1; int permanent2 = p2.isPermanent() ? -1 : 1; int result = Integer.compare(permanent1, permanent2); if( result == 0 ) { [... the rest ] } return result;`

Comment: Or you can make use of the fact that Collections.sort() is a stable sort and first do this sort, then do a second sort which only compares isPermanent(). It'll leave the ID sorting in place.

Comment: i want to sort only if both p1 & p2 are NOT permanent but if( result == 0 ) { [... the rest ]  is when both ARE permanent right?

Comment: result == 0 is if they are both of the same group, either permanent or nonpermanent, yes. In this case, isPermanent() didn't make a difference, so the rest of the criteria will determine which comes first.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not perform three tests?

Non-negative comes before negative.
`return` if exactly one is negative.

If both are negative,
The larger value comes before the smaller value.

If both are non-negative,
The smaller value comes before the larger value.

Comment: +1: This is a good example of use a pencil and a paper before programming.

Answer (score 0):

Compare returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

```
if( p1.id * p2.id < 0 ) {
    // opposite sign
    // if p1 is negative, p2 is positive, p1 is greater than p2
    // otherwise p1 is positive, p2 is negative, p1 is less than p2
    return -p1.id;
}
if( p1.id > 0 && p2.id > 0 || p1.id + p2.id >= 0) {
    // both positive, normal ordering or a zero and a positive number, also normal ordering
    return p1.id - p2.id;
}
if( p1.id <0 && p2.id < 0 ){
    // both negative, inverse ordering
    return p2.id - p1.id;
}
// zero and a negative number, zero comes first
if( p1.id == 0 ) {
    return -1;
}
return 1;
```

[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, -1, -2]

Answer (score 0):

It's obscure but you can do

```
Integer.compare(x >= 0 ? x + Integer.MIN_VALUE : ~x, y >= 0 ? y + Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

or even more obscure

```
Integer.compare(x ^ (-1 << ~(x >> -1)), y ^ (-1 << ~(y >> -1)))
```

Note: the same formula will work for `long`s ;)

This maps [0, Integer.MAX_VALUE] to [Integer.MIN_VALUE, -1] and [Integer.MIN_VALUE, -1] is flipped to [0, Integer.MAX_VALUE]